# How to load a grid in javascript using HTML

Tags: javascript, html, model-view-controller

I'm using  the following function to ready and draw the grid as soon as the HTML page is clicked

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    FillGrid();
});
```

And I'm using the following FillGrid function to draw and show the data from the MSSQL

```
function FillGrid() {
    //if ($('#grid').length == 1) {
    // $('#grid tr').not(':first-child').remove();
    $.ajax({

        //beforeSend: function () {
        //    $('.grid').show();
        //    $("#loadingProjects").show();
        //},
        //complete: function () {
        //    ShowGrid();
        //    $("#loadingProjects").hide();
        //},
       // method: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {
            //if (data.length == 0) {
            //    $('<tr><td colspan="4">No Record Found</td></tr>').appendTo($('#grid'));
            //}
            $.each(data, function (index, item) {

                $('<tr>' +
                    '<td>' + item.ReservationDate + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + item.Name1 + '</td>' +
                    '</tr>').appendTo($('#grid'));
            });
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
}
```

And this is my HTML code of the grid.

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="grid" style="display:none;">
  <tr>
    <th>Reservation No</th>
    <th>Name</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But the grid is never been drawn when its loaded.
Is this correct or am I'm doing something wrong.

Can anyone help me? This is for a school project.

Comment: Is the `url` parameter also missing in your code? Do you ever change the `style="display:none;"` after the ajax call?

Comment: @AlonEitan I got another function that accepts the users'  inputs after it is sent to MSSQL it returns back the value. And inside of that function in the success area, I have called this function name. And when this function is called i wanna create the grid and show the data to the user